# App Validation Error Help: AppResource in packaged app not found

Tags: validation, firefox-os

I'm pulling my hair out with this app validator:

I get the following error, but the file is not missing from that path.

> Resource in packaged app not found.
>
> Error: A icon within a packaged app is referenced, but the path used
>   does not point to a valid item in the package.
>
> Requested resource: FriendFinder/images/logo120.png manifest.webapp

=============================

Here is my manifest:

```
{
    "name": "FriendFinder",
    "launch_path": "/index.html",
    "description": "FriendFinder GPS APP",
    "icons": {
         "16": "/FriendFinder/images/logo16.png",
        "32": "/FriendFinder/images/logo32.png",
         "60": "/FriendFinder/images/logo60.png",
        "64": "/FriendFinder/images/logo64.png",
        "90": "/FriendFinder/images/logo90.png",
        "120": "/FriendFinder/images/logo120.png",
        "128": "/FriendFinder/images/logo128.png",
        "256": "/FriendFinder/images/logo256.png"
    },
    "developer": {
        "name": "Haim Lichaa",
        "url": "http://wormholesoft.com/ffos/FriendFinder"
    },
    "installs_allowed_from": ["*"],
    "default_locale": "en",
    "permissions": {
        "geolocation": {
            "description" : "Marking out user location"
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that you don't have logo120.png in the /FriendFinder/images/ folder, or you added the wrong path to your file. You may also want to check if logo120.png exist, if it's 120 x 120 pixels.

**Update**

After looking at your packaged app, you need to remove /FriendFinder in front of all links to icons as they are directly in the images' folder. I just tried it, and I passed the validation.

Comment: LOL. I wish it were that simple.  I checked that before posting.   The file is there is really 120 px.

Comment: I'd take either the logo256.png or logo128.png, resize it to 120px and save it as logo120.png, replacing the old one, just in case.

Comment: I think you submitted your application to the marketplace, did one of these solutions solved your problem? If not, what did you do?